# Silverlight 4, Google Chrome, and HttpWebRequest problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, google-chrome, httpwebrequest, silverlight-4.0

My Silvrlight 4 application hosted in ASP.NET MVC 2 working fine when used through Internet Explorer 8, both in development server and remote web server (IIS 6.0). However when I try to browse through Google Chrome (version 5.0.375.70) it throws "remote server returned not found" error. The code causing the problem is the following:

```
public class MyWebClient
{
  private HttpWebRequest _request;
  private Uri _uri;
  private AsyncOperation _asyncOp;

  public MyWebClient(Uri uri)
  { 
    _uri = uri; 
  }

  public void Start(XElement data)
  {
    _asyncOp = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);
    _data = data;
    _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_uri);
    _request.Method = "POST";
    _request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(BeginRequest), null);
  }

  private void BeginRequest(IAsyncResult result)
  {
    Stream stream = _request.EndGetRequestStream(result);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
      writer.Write(((XElement)_data).ToString());
    }
    stream.Close();
    _request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(BeginResponse), null);
  }

  private void BeginResponse(IAsyncResult result)
  {
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)_request.EndGetResponse(result);
    if (response != null)
    {
       //process returned data
        ...
    }
  }
  ...
 }
```

In short, the above code sends some XML data to web server (to ASP.NET MVC controller) and gets back a processed data. It works when I use Internet Explorer 8. Can someone please explain what is the problem with Google Chrome?

Comment: Have you looked at the IIS logs to check if the URI and parameters are correct from Chrome ? IE has the - nice - habit of HTML encoding parameters automatically. I don't know if Chrome does it (Firefox does not).

Comment: I checked log files:
Chrome: 2010-06-15 01:45:39 W3SVC1452470319 10.1.1.22 POST /AppServices/ProcessData - 80 - 10.1.12.74 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+5.1;+en-US)+AppleWebKit/533.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/5.0.375.70+Safari/533.4 500 0 0

IE: 2010-06-15 01:48:14 W3SVC1452470319 10.1.1.22 POST /AppServices/ProcessData - 80 - 10.1.12.74 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 200 0 0

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is related to ASP.NET MVC route handling with Google Chrome so opened a new question:

[ASP.NET MVC routing issue with Google Chrome client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043099/asp-net-mvc-routing-issue-with-google-chrome-client)